# Is it possible to build parcels for cloudera manager?

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

Cloudera manager seems to recommend using parcels for managing the hadoop cluster. I would like to be able to build parcels out of hive trunk for instance. Is it possible to build parcels for cloudera manager?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is.  You need to use the [Cloudera Manager Extensions](https://github.com/cloudera/cm_ext) software, located on github.

Be sure to check the wiki page on github, as it has a comprehensive set of instructions on the structure for the [parcel metadata](https://github.com/cloudera/cm_ext/wiki/The%20parcel%20format), how to [build the parcel](https://github.com/cloudera/cm_ext/wiki/Building-a-parcel) itself, and the [format of the parcel repository](https://github.com/cloudera/cm_ext/wiki/The-parcel-repository-format).

Comment: There biggest limitation about cloudera parcels is that its not possible to build parcel with different versions of same software, like hive 1.0 and hive 2.0, for instance.